# How to prove that the ellipse is a periodic orbit knowing that the orbital derivative of a function V is zero on there

Tags: derivatives, conic-sections, mathematical-modeling, periodic-functions, biology

The question is as follows:

Show that the orbital derivative of the function $V=(1-x^2-2y^2)^2$ is zero on the ellipse $x^2+2y^2=1$, and explain why you can deduce that the ellipse is a periodic orbit.

So I've proved the first part:
$$V'=2(1-x^2-2y^2)(-2xx'-4yy')$$ ($V'$ denotes the orbital derivative and $x'$ and $y'$ are the derivatives of $x$ and $y$ respectively)

Now taking the orbit: $2y^2=1-x^2$ and substituting on $V'$, we get zero.

My question is that now I don't know how to proceed to show that it is periodic...

Thank you

Comment: You want the ellipse to be a periodic orbit of which equation?

Comment: @Jonas I have a dynamical system:

x' = x*(1-x^2-2*y^2) - 2*y*(1+y) ;
y' = y*(1-x^2-2*y^2) + x*(1+y)

and I've calculated its fixed points and stability (the only fixed point is (0,0) which is unstable)

So now,  I've been given that function, V, and I need to show that the ellipse is a periodic orbit (knowing that  the orbital derivative of V is zero on the ellipse)

Thanks for answer

Comment: @Jonas sorry I was editing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since
$$
x' = x(1-x^2-2y^2) - 2y(1+y),\quad
y' = y(1-x^2-2y^2) + x(1+y),
$$
you have
$$
xx'+2yy'=(x^2+2y^2)(1-x^2-2y^2)
$$
and so
$$
V'=-4(1-x^2-2y^2)^2(x^2+2y^2).
$$
Hence, for points close to the ellipse but outside the ellipse you have $V'<0$.

This implies that the ellipse is a periodic orbit since we know how the orbits behave in its neighborhood (just draw it).

Comment: Thank you. Just one more question:  How should I proceed now to determine whether this periodic orbit is stable or unstable? I know that the only fixed point of the dynamical system is unstable (eigenvalues have real part positive) and since we have that expression of V we can easily check that it's a Lyapunov function...

Comment: The orbit is unstable, because orbits "inside" go away from the orbit (because $V'<0$).